# Search within many table php with wildcard

Tags: php, mysql

please help me, i want to make search query but list of table is not shown in php but it work in mysql..here is my code

```
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1=1" work perfectly
$sql = "SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema like 'rft%') a where 1=1";

if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) 
{   // if there is a search parameter, $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter

//search based on input 
$sql.=" AND ( Code LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    
$sql.=" OR Year LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
}
 //start search after input 
 $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");

 $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

continue here

```
 // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
 $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]." ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";

 /* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */   
 $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) 
{  // preparing an array
$nestedData=array(); 

$nestedData[] = $row["Type"];
$nestedData[] = $row["Code"];
$nestedData[] = $row["Year"];

$data[] = $nestedData;
}
```

Comment: Output `$sql` and see if you can run it in mysql directly

Comment: echo the sql query formed at end, run the query in db. If some error comes, paste here

Comment: Of course it will not be shown because you did not query it. you just give the variable `$sql` a value;

Comment: i have edit it to show my query..i forgot to mention,if i use normal select such as "select * from table" it work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only select `table_name` from `information_schema.tables` and later you do your `WHERE code=...`. There is no `Code` in the result of your select, so this can't work.

If I get correctly what you are trying to do you have to do it in two steps like this:

```
// get all table names:
$tquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema like 'rft%'");
while ($table = mysqli_fetch_array($tquery)) {
    // do your query per table
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM " . $table['table_name'] . " WHERE ( Code LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql .=" OR Year LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' )";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
        // do what you want with $row
    }
}
```